# Current limiter for VOD3120AB

Tags: power-supply, resistors, current-limiting, power-dissipation

I want to supply [VOD3120AB](https://www.vishay.com/docs/84921/vod3120ab.pdf) with a voltage of **24v/2A from Power Supply**. What is the value of the **Resistor** that I must add to the **VCC** of the **VOD3120AB** so that the **VOD3120AB** works properly?

Information from the datasheet like this:

1. Wide operating VCC range: 15V to 30V
2. ICC = 3.5 mA maximum supply current
3. Output power dissipation Pdiss 250mW

I tried to calculate like this:

R = V/I
= 24/0.0035
= 6857 ohm

P = I^2 * R
= (0.0035^2) * 6857
= 0.084 watt

I must select R with resistance 6857 ohm and power dissipation = 0.084 watt.
Maybe Resistor  6k8/0.125 watt, Its correct?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *What is the value of the Resistor that I must add to the VCC of the
> VOD3120AB so that the VOD3120AB works properly?*

You are thinking about this incorrectly. Just supply the device with 24 volts and that is sufficient. It'll take a quiescent current of less than 3.5 mA and it's job done. Test circuit from [data sheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/84921/vod3120ab.pdf): -

[image]

The maximum power dissipation is the losses of the device when driving a fully rated load such as a MOSFET's gate-source capacitance. Make sure you don't exceed this value by choosing your MOSFET and operating frequency carefully.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply 15 V to 30 V to the Vcc pin, and the device will draw whatever current it requires - no need for any current limiting resistor there.

However, the input seems to be an LED, so you will need to add a current-limiting resistor in series with it to limit the LED current to 7 - 16 mA, as stated in the "Recommended Operating Condition" table.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to powering the *LED* from 24V, first pick the desired current, say 20mA and use Ohm's Law.

$$ E = I \cdot R $$

$$ 24V = 0.02A \cdot R $$

Then realize that a forward-biased LED is going to drop some voltage, say 1.8V when powered at 20mA.  So subtract this from the supply voltage.

$$ 24V - 1.8V = 0.02A \cdot R $$

$$ 22.2V = 0.02A \cdot R $$

Then rearrange to solve for R by dividing both sides by current (the opposite of multiplying current, so R is left by itself on the right side.)

$$ \frac{22.2V}{0.02A} = \frac{\require{cancel}\bcancel{0.02A} \cdot R}{\bcancel{0.02A}} $$

$$ \frac{22.2V}{0.02A} = R $$

$$ 1110 \Omega = R $$

Comment: I have to keep the input (left) and output (right) with different ground (different power supply), because the input side will be connected to the microcontroller with a voltage of 3.3v and a current of 10mA, while the output side will be connected to a voltage of 24v and a current of 2A . Intentionally isolated so that the large electric current from the MOSFET does not damage the microcontroller. Thank you.